# Accessing frontmatter from outside using vue 3 and unplugin-vue-markdown package

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I'm currently working on a `Vue 3` project and using the `unplugin-vue-markdown` package to render markdown content. I have frontmatter metadata in my markdown files that I need to access in my `Vue component`.

Code Snippets:

markdown:

```
---
title: My Markdown Title
otherData: Some Value
---
## Content
This is my markdown content.
```

Vue Component:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ frontmatter.title }}</h1>
    <!-- ...other content -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Packages and Versions:

Vue: 3.3.4

unplugin-vue-markdown: 0.24.2

I've reviewed the documentation of `unplugin-vue-markdown` but haven't found a solution that addresses accessing frontmatter from outside the markdown file.